# Why use "or" instead of "xor" in definitions?

Tags: xml, haskell, types, computer-science, definition

This might be a trivial question but I really can't find the answer anywhere. There is a convention in computer science which I find peculiar.

In [haskell datatypes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type) can be defined like this:

```
data Bool = False | True
```

In xml [qualified names](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames) are defined like this:

```
QName   ::=   PrefixedName | UnprefixedName
```

There are probably more similar examples but this should suffice.

Usually [it is well understood](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.7C) that `|` (pipe or bar) should be read as `or`. But this seems strange. `A or B` is true also when both A and B are true. While it makes sense in the first example (there is a possibility that something is `True` and `False` at the same time, but we implicitly assume the law of non-contradiction), it doesn't in the second: something is either a `PrefixedName` or an `UnprefixedName` it can't be both.

So why is this often put like this? Why not use exclusive or? Are there any non-conventional reasons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `data X = A | B` notation should not really be understood as a logical OR at all (though that corresponds quite well to the intuitive meaning). What it really means is that `X` is a *sum type* of `A` and `B`, i.e. a [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct). Now, the *product* operation on booleans is in fact AND, and so the dual would quite naturally be OR.

Though then again, the sum operation on a vector space of booleans is actually XOR so we're turning circles a bit...

I just wouldn't read too much into this. `|` is simply a symbol; in C-like languages it happens to also mean bitwise OR, but the actual logical OR is generally denoted differently, be it `||` or `∨`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I should have seen a similarity to regex `|` operator. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

`|` has a long history of being used to separate items in a list of mutually exclusive choices:

1. Regular expressions: `a* | b*` means a string can either be 0 or more `a`s or 0 or more `b`s, but not both.
2. Backus-Naur form for representing context-free grammars:

   ```
   Expr ::= Term | Expr AddOp Term
   ```

   in which an expression can either be a single term, or another expression combined with a term with an addition operator. (It cannot be both simultaneously.)
3. Usage messages for command-line programs:

   ```
   git branch (-d | -D) [-r] <branchname>...
   ```

   Here the `git branch` command can take either the `-d` or the `-D` option, but not both in the same invocation.

The `data` statement in Haskell continues this tradition; it is unrelated to the use of `|` as a logical or bit-wise operator.

(If anything, it is possible that the use of `|` for bitwise `OR` was inspired by Backus-Naur form, in which case you could be asking why `|` is used for `OR` instead of `XOR`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the meaning of "or" here is in a literal sense as opposed to a mathematical sense. Using the term "or" means that the value can have one value, or another. It is not an operator which aims to determine a truth value.

While it may not be entirely logical to use an "or" operator sign for this, it does a good enough job at getting the point across for a reader. This clarity is ultimately the thing a language is striving for. As long as a greater proportion of readers is capable of interpreting it as a "literal" usage as opposed to a "mathematical" operator usage, using or in a literal sense means you, as a language, are doing a better job at getting your point across, making the method superior to using something such as XOR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the first part is clearly incorrect. There are some natural language contexts in which you can use `or` meaning `both` (e.g. "Do you want an apple or a pear? -Both, please."). Even more, in language we use words as `or` and `and` in a way which allows to determine a "truth value".